# (PERCY) Warning: skipping visual tests. PERCY_TOKEN was not provided

Tags: javascript, json, powershell, warnings, snapshot

I'm getting this error below everytime I try to run 'npx percy exec -- node snapshots.js'.

**PowerShell Terminal**

*Problem Image* ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCSj6.png

I have followed this Tutorial -> https://docs.percy.io/docs/percyscript-tutorial

Anyone know how to solve this? I looked everywhere and found nothing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell has a different syntax for working with Environment Variables.

Try this:

```
$env:PERCY_TOKEN = "token"
```

[Powershell Help - About Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 1):

To set up PERCY_TOKEN on windows we have to use powershell.

```
1.Open powershell on windows

2. Go to project library through commands cd, cd..

3.Set the PERCY_TOKEN $env:PERCY_TOKEN='your token'

4. Then run your project using powershell through your command npm run test:percy
```

Comment: What if the problem is occurring in Mac? I tried everything I know but it would not work.
`
[percy] Skipping visual tests
[percy] Error: Missing Percy token
[percy] Running "cypress run"
`